# Android Paypal One time Payment

Tags: android, paypal

Does any one know, or is it possible  to do one time payment, with paypal in android ?

Consider the senario.

- **Buyer purchases installs free
  application.**
- **Clicks on paypal module and makes
  in-app payment, purchases feature
  successfully.**
- **Buyer deletes application. All
  information including the feature
  purchase enty in database is deleted.**
- **Buyer reinstalls the application.**

Here is the catch, if he wants to use the feature he will have to do a re-purchase.
Which I wann to avoid in my application. 
This is taken care in iPhone in-app purchase.
That is if a buyer has already purchased an feature or in-app item, and if he trys to repurchase it (item has been set to one time payment), the in-app purchase transaction will succeed without the user actually having to repay for the item.

Is there an solution for this can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Currently PayPal doesn't seem to support this, you'll have to implement approptiate logic with your own server side (register purchases in a table and query it before performing new purchase).
All items in PayPal are 'consumable' to use Apple's terms.